# Google maps and RAILS

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

my question is about the best way to populate a map in android using data from a RAILS web page... the way i'm doing it now is:

i have a json with the data (latitude, longitude and some other atributes of the point)
i use httpclient to get the information, then i put the data into a list and then i populate the map... it's working fine currently but it's way too slow

is there a better way to do this?

also i would like to know a way the i can draw a route with my finger on android

Comment: Is the rails application slow or the android app.

Comment: the android app is loading the markers way too slow on my MapView

Comment: An alternative is to store latitude, longitude and other attributes of the point in a database on the Android device. That should speed things up.

Comment: i thought of that,...
but the app has the potential to grow exponentially, will the memory on the phone be sufficient to allow us to not worry about the number of points we can store?